# Autocomplete Issue Via Data.xml

Tags: jquery, xml, autocomplete

Need a little help in my Autocomplete Search Function in JS here is my code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var myArr = [];

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml,
    complete: setupAC,
    failure: function(data) {
     alert("XML File could not be found");
   }
 });

 function parseXml(xml)
 {
   $(xml).find("name").each(function()
   {
        myArr.push({ url: 'example.com/'+$(this).attr("href"), label: $(this).text()});
   });
 }

 function setupAC() {
   $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
   source: myArr,
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {
     $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.label);
     window.location.href = ui.item.url;
   }
  });
 }
});
</script>
```

Here is a Sample of Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<name href="dir-cats/government-telephone-directory/administration-contacts/">Administration Contacts</name>
<name href="dir-cats/marketing-advertising/advertisers/">Advertisers</name>
<name href="dir-cats/business-industry/agricultural-implements-machinery%e2%80%8e/">Agricultural Implements &amp; Machinery‎</name>
<name href="dir-cats/home-furnishing/aluminum-glassworks/">Aluminum &a
</data>
```

When i change the  to  and also change this in my Script code my search stop showing result.

Can someone guide me what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is not correct, it miss a closing  tag :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <name href="dir-cats/government-telephone-directory/administration-contacts/">Administration Contacts</name>
    <name href="dir-cats/marketing-advertising/advertisers/">Advertisers</name>
    <name href="dir-cats/business-industry/agricultural-implements-machinery%e2%80%8e/">Agricultural Implements &amp; Machinery‎</name>
    <name href="dir-cats/home-furnishing/aluminum-glassworks/">Aluminum</name>
</data>
```

With this correct XML, it works fine

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. but that is a sample file my original file is having proper closing tags...

Comment: @saku4388 It worked fine when I tried, do you have a browser extension that might affect the expected behavior ?